# How to buy a replacement display for laptop?

Tags: laptop, displays

I've got an Acer A515-51-517Y. The laptop developed horizontal cracks on the bezels (possibly because the hinges needed lubrication) and eventually the stress from opening the laptop caused the display to crack slightly, and now I can close the lid, for fear of making the crack grow. It came with a 1366x768 terrible display, so I would like buy an FHD IPS display (and a bezel) to replace it.

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mUdu9C8JOjE&t=97s) video recommends a display with Model B156HAN02.1. However, I live in Kerala, India, and most Chinese online retailers have delivery charges about 100$ (about the same as the display) and there could be unprecedented customs charges. How can I go about procuring this display for an acceptable price?

Thank you

Comment: What is an acceptable price? O jea, and laptops mostly come with non-replacable displays, which I also don't like

Comment: About 100 dollars is doable for a good quality FHD IPS display.